# uploading asset to strapi with cloudinary gives error : ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty

Tags: node.js, api, rest, strapi, cloudinary

I was following this [tutorial](https://%20https://strapi.io/blog/add-cloudinary-support-to-your-strapi-application) to create a web app that uses Cloudinary as a image host , I followed all the steps mentioned in it but when i try to add a image it gives me this error [ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZDrB.png) , idk what's causing this , is this some kind of connection error ?

here is my plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({

upload: {
    config:{
    provider: 'cloudinary',
    providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env('+++++++'),
        api_key: env('8+++++++++++'),
        api_secret: env('1T++++++++++++U'),
      
    },
},
```

my .env file , this file also contains other stuff like jwt keys , host , port etc  ,  here is what i added to it

```
--hosts ports etc--
CLOUDINARY_NAME = **********
CLOUDINARY_KEY = ***********
CLOUDINARY_SECRET = ***************
```

my middleware.js file

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
          'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          'media-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Comment: Can you help to check if this could be a version issue as [described in the forum](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4411758853778-Strapi-Clouinary-connection-do-not-work). Alternatively, there are also other good resources as described [here](https://cptcrunchy.medium.com/configuring-cloudinary-with-strapi-3-1-4-6dbddc721617) and [here](https://strapi.io/blog/add-cloudinary-support-to-your-strapi-application).

Comment: thanks for answering actually i discovered that you have to define the field name with the cloudinary fields in plugins.js under providerOptions so it becomes 

          cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME','*******'),
          api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY','********'),
          api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET','*********'),
   }

Comment: @SrajanBarkade damn! it happens to me